# Polyline из строки base64

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте!
Хочу построить polyline из строки base64. 
На странице с документацией по методу fromEncodedCoordinates  https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/geometry.LineString.fromEncodedCoordinates-docpage/ есть пример...

Беру строку, при попытке реализации на версии 2.1 линия появляется где-то в Иране https://prnt.sc/hwx155. Хотя если попробовать на версии 1.1, то линия появляется там где нужно https://prnt.sc/hwx1op.

Другой пример: на я.картах построил путь, хочу скопировать строку base64 https://prnt.sc/hwx2vo
На версии 2.1 линия вновь появляется где-то в Иране https://prnt.sc/hwx3m1. На версии 1.1 там где и должна быть линия https://prnt.sc/hwx4eg.

Код https://gist.github.com/cergey-obr/eeec7d23095b9c8c7614b37959527726

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый вечер. Такая ошибка может происходить из-за того, что порядок координат в данных и API не совпадает. В версии 2.1 по умолчанию используется порядок координат "широта, долгота". Пример, видимо, очень старый еще из версии 1.1, где был другой порядок. Вам нужно или при подключении API указать get-параметр coordorder=longlat, или поменять порядок в данных перед шифрованием.

Comment: Помогло, при подключении api указываю параметр coordorder. https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=longlat